# Pseudo elements not showing

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Pseudo elements not showing on a div. I'm using a sprite image but I have tried a non-sprite image as well, yet nothing. I tried multiple strategies, such as positioning absolute, using z-index, margins, etc. I seem to be doing it correctly if I'm not mistaken or apparently I am doing something wrong. I'm new to the community and have searched here and also Google yet no result as to why it is not showing.The code is below in it's most basic try. Thanks to all who take the time to help.

```
.test {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    width:60%;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
     background:url("/imgs/Sprite2.png") repeat-y;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:27px;
    height:100%;
}

.test:before {
    content:"";
    background-position:0 0;
}

.test:after {
    content:"";
    background-position:-55px 0;
}
```

I now have it working. The code is below. I could of sworn that I already tried this but I must have did something wrong the first time I did it.

```
 .test {
     background:#fff;
     width:60%;margin:0  0 60px 5%;
 }

 .test:before,
 .test:after {
     content:"";
     background:url("/imgs/Sprite2.png") repeat-y;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     width:27px;
     height:100%;
 }

 .test:before {
     right:100%;
     background-position:0 0;
 }

 .test:after {
     left:100%;
     background-position:-55px 0;
 }
```

Comment: Could you post a demo that reproduces your problem (and shows your html), at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: I'm testing on all current browsers on a localhost setup. All my css always works. I just started trying to use Pseudo elements. to remove empty spans for image borders and cleaner markup/semantics.@David Thomas I'm going to give it a shot on JS Fiddle now.

Comment: Quick note to avoid others making the same stupid mistake I have: if the outer element has `overflow` set to `hidden`, the `:after` pseudo element won't show...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed adding content to those elements

Comment: I missed adding `content: " ";` too. If you forget it, the pseudo element does not show up!

Comment: Just in case anyone else reads this you should use `::before` or `::after`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heres's the corrected answer, since I never showed that I answered it using the button. I just placed it in the top thinking that it would be considered answered. Basically I must've done something wrong the first time somewhere. Hope this helps people who have had problems similar to mines.

```
.test {
    background: #fff;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 0 60px 5%
}

.test:before, .test:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("/imgs/Sprite2.png") repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 27px;
    height: 100%
}

.test:before {
    right: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0
}

.test:after {
    left: 100%;
    background-position: -55px 0
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### EDITED:

This is an issue of `height:100%;` mentioned in `.test:before,.test:after`

You need to mention `height:100%` to `.test` and for `html` and `body` also,

See below the suggested changes in your CSS:

**Try this:**

```
body, html { height: 100%; }

.test{ 
    display:inline-block; 
    background:#fff; 
    width:60%;
    height: 100%; /*added height*/
}

.test:before,
.test:after{
    content:"";
    background:url("/imgs/Sprite2.png") repeat-y;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:27px;
    height:100%;   
}

.test:before{ background-position:0 0 }
.test:after{ background-position:-55px 0 }
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rYXm8/)

Comment: `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are displayed as `inline` elements. So you need to specify `display` property for them. You can read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: @David Thomas and user1693535: Updated my answer with a possible solution according to my thoughts. I may be wrong.

Comment: I tried using only display:block,yet still nothing, I also just changed the code to how you wrote it A.K. Same result nothing. I'm bugging out here.

Comment: I just tried that as well A.K. I did not have body, html set to height 100%, so i did that, and I added the 100% height to the div which I already tried yet, still nada.

Comment: @Jezen Thomas - What do you mean?

Comment: @user1693535: on which browser you are testing?

Comment: Here's a link without using images of course. I have no url for the images because I'm on a localhost setup. It should be red where the images are supposed to be. http://jsfiddle.net/dnS7s/2/embedded/result/

Comment: If you use fixed height with 100% width: see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/79RMn/

Comment: Here's an updated link. It should be red where the images are supposed to be. jsfiddle.net/dnS7s/2/embedded/result

Comment: @A.K Why would I use a fixed height when I have a responsive design. I mean that with no disrespect. The height will adjust according to relative content+margins within the div.

Comment: Also the red bars should be on left and right side, not top and bottom. Thats why I have repeat-y on the sprite image.

Comment: I'm not sure how the 100% height works out when I will have other divs/content under/below it within the main div.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem was your css properties not declared/arranged properly. From what I've seen, you've declared first your **background-image** but the **content** was declared last with the **background-position**.

And I had my own problem on Glyphicon font which was not showing before until I implemented what keaukraine had mentioned about declaring **display** property.

But sometimes people tend to forget declaring the **content** property that will be resulted the expected result to disappear.

So it should be arranged something like this:

```
element:before {
  content: "\e013"; // or content: ""
  background:url("background_image.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```